# Create independent objects using operator * on list

Tags: python

I'm trying to initialize a bi-dimentional (3x3) list without typing all elements, since they are all the same.

However, it seems that only the first line of this matrix is really created as a new object, and the subsequent lines are just references to the first line.

How could I create all lines are independent objects?

Here's an example to illustrate this:

```
# Create a bi-dimentional list
a=[[''] * 3] * 3
print a
>>>[['', '', ''], ['', '', ''], ['', '', '']]

# change a single element, on first line
# notice that it will change also the elements at other lines
a[0][1] = 'x'
print a
[['', 'x', ''], ['', 'x', ''], ['', 'x', '']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `range()`:

```
a = [[''] * 3 for _ in range(3)]
```

Using `*` with list (and more generally with objects) actually just create references, you have to create new lists.

Answer (score 0):

you could do:

```
a = ['','','']
b = ['','','']
c = ['','','']

d = [a, b, c]
```

not sure it's what you're after, but d[0][1] = 'x' returns:

```
[['','x',''],['','',''],['','','']]
```

because even an assignment like a=b=c=[] just creates three references to the same object, and you end up with the same issue.

Comment: Pointer isn't a good term here. Prefer _reference_.